# A Surface view and a canvas to move Bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

I have a `SurfaceView` and I want the `Bitmap Logo` inside it in the `canvas` to be movable

What I'm doing wrong ?

```
static float x, y;
Bitmap logo;

SurfaceView ss = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.svSS);   
    logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);

    x = 40;
    y = 415;
    ss.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        switch(me.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x = me.getX();
            y = me.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x = me.getX();
            y = me.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x = me.getX();
            y = me.getY();
            break;
            }
        return true;
        }
    });

public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    Thread t = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean isItOK = false;


    public OurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();

    }
    public void run (){
        while (isItOK == true){
            //canvas DRAWING
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawARGB(255, 200, 100, 100);
            c.drawBitmap(logo, x,y,null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
    public void pause(){
        isItOK = false;
        while(true){
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        t = null;
    }
    public void resume(){
        isItOK = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }
}
```

Now the surface view is just black .. nothing happens also its not colored `200, 100, 100`

Comment: you need to implement `onDraw(Canvas c)` method within your `OurView` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might forget to implement `onDraw(Canvas c)` method in your `OurView` class, and move the `onTouchEvent` inside the class.

The class structure should like this:

```
public class OurView extends View implements Runnable {

//...your runnable stuff here
//...Runnable stuff means your run(), pause() etc.

  public OurView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    //your constructor stuff here
    // your constructor, do you find the similar stuff to this you wrote? That's your constructor, so you can just add:
    holder = getHolder();
}

protected void onDraw (Canvas c) {

    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y);
//set colour, draw bitmap here, onDraw() will be called automatically, so just call invalidate(); when you need to "refresh" the view
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();

    swith(e.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
     ...
    }
}
}
```

For more explicit example and reference please go:

[Implementing a Custom View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#)

[Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom)

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm kinda new .. what do you mean by constructor, and runnable stuff ? sorry <<

Comment: @JohnAppleSim Please check my improved answer

Comment: I tried it nothing worked, http://pastebin.com/1b2YgcA7 ( the code at the last ) .. btw what i want is the widget surface vew ( from xml ) not the whole screen is a surface view